# Variable storing payment method in ubercart order

Tags: ubercart

Seems easy but I am not able to figure it. I am using ubercart module in drupal 7, I am few payment methods like paypal, innovate and free method. All the 3 payment methods are activated, When a user places any order he has to choose which payment method he want to go for, if he is going for free method,

I need to know which variable is storing this payment method value,it should be like $order->method or $order->type same like other variables like $order->order_id,$order->billing_first_name.

In short I should come to know which payment method is chosen for a particular order.

If any buddy knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you're looking for is is `$order->payment_method`.

Comment: may I know how to get [ucxf_name]? (created by Extra Fields Checkout Pane module)